# How to push new array in react native object

Tags: arrays, react-native, array-push

i have following array

```
[{

        "games1": [{
            "playername": "1"
        }]
    },
    {

        "games2": [{
                "playername": "1"
            },
            {
                "playername": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i want add new array playername2 at games1 how to push
I want this type of result

```
        "games1": [{
                "playername": "1"
            }, {
                "playername": "2"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this

```
let myArray = [
    {
      games1: [
        {
          playername: '1',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      games2: [
        {
          playername: '1',
        },
        {
          playername: '2',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  myArray[0].games1.push({playername:'2'});
```

Comment: var arrayname= "games1", myArray[0].arrayname.push({playername:'2'});     how to do this